# Slick2d and a controller. button function correspondance?

Tags: java, controller, slick2d, logitech, d-pad

I'm using slick2d and a Logitech cordless Rumblepad 2 controller
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGSeZ.jpg

I need help mapping the buttons to the Input class's functions.

So far i've figured out that the D-PAD up, down left and right map to the isControllerDIRECTION functions, and moving the left analog stick is the same.

I have also mapped buttons 1, 2 and 3 to be isButtonBUTTONNRPressed functions.

But what about the rest?

Comment: any1? really need this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this thread, it explains how controller buttons are assigned: 
http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3271&view=next